# How to rewrite certain pages but not CSS, JS etc?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying for at least 4 hours to fix this problem on my own and have scoured through several hundreds of Stack Overflow pages and other forums in search of a solution, but I can't seem to solve this simple problem.

The contents are arranged as follows:

```
-- index.php
  -- js
       - script.js
  -- css
       - style.css
  -- images
       - image.png
```

In the website, I need`index.php?dept=foo` to be rewritten as `dept/foo`. This works with the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^dept/(\w+)/?$ index.php?dept=$1 [NC]
```

But then the CSS, JS and images won't load any more.

The CSS and JS files are currently are currently included as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

I tried changing the URLs to have absolute paths (i.e. `/css/style.css` too`, but that didn't fix it either).

How can I correctly fix the problem?

Comment: What is correct and working URL of `style.css`?

Comment: @anubhava: http://localhost/live/css/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dept/(\w+)/?$ index.php?dept=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/live/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

You can keep your CSS path as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```